# Json Deserialize in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

How to use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject with below Json

```
[{
  "attributes" : {
    "type" : "User",
    "url" : "/xx/xx/xx"
  },
  "Id" : "1",
  "Name" : "abc"
},{
  "attributes" : {
    "type" : "User",
    "url" : "/xx/xx/xx"
  },
  "Id" : "2",
  "Name" : "abc"
},{
  "attributes" : {
    "type" : "User",
    "url" : "/xx/xx/xx"
  },
  "Id" : "3",
  "Name" : "abc"
}]
```

These are my class

```
public class Attributes
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Attributes attributes { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried with

```
var c = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <RootObject>(jsonText);
```

Comment: So you tried it .. *and*? (Note that the JSON root object is an *array*.)

Comment: 0 Flags remaining... This is duplicate of 100s of posts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Json actually represents an array of `RootObject` instances. Try this:

```
var c = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject[]>(jsonText);
```

Or possibly

```
var c = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(jsonText);
```

Or even

```
var c = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<RootObject>>(jsonText);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON is actually an array, so try deserializing it into `RootObject[]`:

```
var c = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject[]>(jsonText);
```

Answer (score 1):

You `json` is a array (or collection), try to deserialize it using the array type:

```
var c = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject[]>(jsonText);
```

Or any other type of collection, for sample:

```
var c = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<RootObject>>(jsonText);
var c = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ICollection<RootObject>>(jsonText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try telling the deserializer what you're expecting to deserialize to, in this case RootObject.
According to the  [documentation of the method you're currently calling](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm) `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject Method (String)` returns a .net object.

While [this method](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject__1.htm) `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T> Method (String)` returns the specified type.
for example:

```
public class Attributes
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Attributes attributes { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

RootObject c = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonText);
```